Heating element with SSR
I have a 3-phase, 240 V, 3 kW heating element that I intend to control via PLC ==> PWM==> SSR.
In case this control methods fails electrically, how do I prevent (limit) my heating element to go on full blast?

Standard industrial control strategy is to add a safety or control "loop break" safety shutoff. It could use a simple thermostat or a separate temperature probe with controller and contactor. Depending on the risk to life and property, you might want to make this independent of the PLC so that if it freezes you still have protection.

Some manufacturers call this independent measurement a "limit" channel.  If a Limit channel goes over-temperature, then the system is latched OFF until manually reset.
In addition, its good practice that your temperature sensors and conditioners are designed and configured to output a maximum temperature if they fail (like if one becomes disconnected), thereby removing a heat request if the sensor fails.

Depending on the consequences when failure occurs you can use several methods.
An independent limit controller is one method. It has to be completely independent not just introducing an overridden control signal since the SSR could (and they frequently do) fail 'on'. The sensor should also be independent. Whatever breaks the power does not need to have a long life in terms of switching operations (assuming you prevent that from happening), but it does have to be appropriately reliable to actually open when called to do so. Gas controls for commercial applications frequently have industry agency approved (for insurance purposes) limit controllers with a manual reset.
Other methods are to introduce a bimetal thermostat with a manual reset or a thermal fuse. Since you have 3-phase you'd need something like a contactor to do the actual switching.
If the consequences are particularly serious you may wish to have more than one fully independent scheme to mitigate the consequences of a failure.
